# Error Installing Intellij idea on ubuntu wsl

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have downloaded the ubuntu wsl. I have also downloaded the intellij idea CE tar from the website. I am getting the below error when i try to run ./idea.sh

```
    StartupError: Unable to detect graphic environment.
```

I have added JAVA_HOME to my PATH as well. Below are some details

java --version

```
    openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

lsb_release -a

```
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
  Release:        18.04
  Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-wsl-as-of-2018

Comment: WSL doesn't include (or support?) graphical applications out of the box. @CrazyCoder posted a pretty good link with resources on how to set up an XServer so that you can run graphical applications on top of WSL, but be warned that they will have more latency than native apps. Without a more specific use case, you are probably better off just running IntelliJ natively on Windows.